# Blaze: Logic (Not, Or, And…) in {{#if}} statement

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Is there a way to do logic operation in {{#if}} statement?
I was hoping for something like:

```
{{#if A && B}}
  some html
{{/if}}
```

I couldn’t find documentation about logic in blaze, so I guess it’s not supported. I just wanted to be sure. Sorry for the rather stupid question...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Billy Bob suggests, you would need parameterized helpers. Here are two global helpers you could use in any context:

```
Template.registerHelper('and',(a,b)=>{
  return a && b;
});
Template.registerHelper('or',(a,b)=>{
  return a || b;
});
```

Then you could use these with:

```
{{#if and a b}}
  a and b are both true-ish
{{/if}}
{{#if or a b}}
  a or b is true-ish
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spacebars is designed to avoid including logic operations in the html. But it does not mean you can't have one : you need to use helpers. Basically, you have 2 conditional cases:

- The simple `{{#if something}}` and its twin `{{#unless something}}` (understand it as "if not"). This is what you want, and your helper would look like this

  ```
  Meteor.yourTemplate.helpers({
    something : function () {
       return A && B
    }
  });
  ```
- The more complicated `{{#if something 'value'}}` where you use an argument for your `something` helper :

  ```
  Meteor.yourTemplate.helpers({
     something : function (value) {
        if (value === true){
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
    });
  ```

Answer (score 2):

here is my version :

```
Template.registerHelper("and", function() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).filter(arg => arg == true).length == arguments.length - 1;
});

Template.registerHelper("or", function() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1).filter(arg => arg == true).length > 0;
});
```

You can now use x arguments to check, like :

```
{{#if and check_1 check_2 check3}}
```

You will notice the slice(0,-1), Blaze add one more argument to the function.