# Accessing the Document using BlazeJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a HTML section that I'd like to toggle on/off using BlazeJS. The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="ui small buttons" style="margin: 2em 0em 2em 0em">
      <button id="driver_button" class="ui green button">Driver</button>
      <div class="or"></div>
      <button id="rider_button" class="ui green button">Rider</button>
</div>

<div id="driver_field">
      <div class="fields">
        {{> Text_Form_Control label="Car Model" placeholder="Toyota Tacoma 2016" value=profile.car errorMessage=(fieldError "car")}}
        {{> Select_Form_Control label="Years Owned" placeholder="3" value=profile.year errorMessage=(fieldError "year")}}
      </div>
      <div class="fields">
        {{> Select_Form_Control label="Number of Seats" placeholder="5" value=profile.seats errorMessage=(fieldError "seats")}}
      </div>
    </div>

<div id="rider_field">
      <div class="fields">
        {{> Text_Form_Control label="Car Model" placeholder="Toyota Tacoma 2016" value=profile.car errorMessage=(fieldError "car")}}
        {{> Select_Form_Control label="Years Owned" placeholder="3" value=profile.year errorMessage=(fieldError "year")}}
      </div>
      <div class="fields">
        {{> Select_Form_Control label="Number of Seats" placeholder="5" value=profile.seats errorMessage=(fieldError "seats")}}
      </div>
</div>
```

And the associated Javascript in the respective file can be found in:

```
Template.Profile_Page.events({
 'click #driver_button'(event, instance) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const driver = instance.getElementById('driver_field');
    const rider = instance.getElementById('rider_field');
    driver.style.display = 'block';
    rider.style.display = 'none';
    console.log('hello');
  },
  'click #rider_button'(event, instance) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const driver = instance.getElementById('driver_field');
    const rider = instance.getElementById('rider_field');
    driver.style.display = 'none';
    rider.style.display = 'block';
  },
})
```

However, instance doesn't correspond to document. How would one access the divs from the events handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want is:

1. To show the relevant section based on what button was clicked.
2. Get values from the fields.

### To show the relevant section based on what button was clicked.

You can use the `#if` condition inside the template to achieve the condition check. Whatever is inside the `#if` condition will render if the if block return true. As of now, there is only boolean support for the template's if condition. More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36499833/1745073)

Whenever one of the button is clicked, you're setting a boolean flag in a [Session](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) variable. And this session variable's value is being passed to the template via the helper - which inturn renders what's inside the if blocks based on the truthiness.

Let me know if this explanation is satisfactory. If not, I can reword it better.

**Template page:**

```
<template name="Profile_Page">
<div class="ui small buttons" style="margin: 2em 0em 2em 0em">
      <button id="driver_button" class="ui green button">Driver</button>
      <div class="or"></div>
      <button id="rider_button" class="ui green button">Rider</button>
</div>

{{#if driverButtonClicked}}
<div id="driver_field">
      <div class="fields">
        {{> Text_Form_Control label="Car Model" placeholder="Toyota Tacoma 2016" value=profile.car errorMessage=(fieldError "car")}}
        {{> Select_Form_Control label="Years Owned" placeholder="3" value=profile.year errorMessage=(fieldError "year")}}
      </div>
      <div class="fields">
        {{> Select_Form_Control label="Number of Seats" placeholder="5" value=profile.seats errorMessage=(fieldError "seats")}}
      </div>
    </div>
{{/if}}

{{#if riderButtonClicked}}
<div id="rider_field">
      <div class="fields">
        {{> Text_Form_Control label="Car Model" placeholder="Toyota Tacoma 2016" value=profile.car errorMessage=(fieldError "car")}}
        {{> Select_Form_Control label="Years Owned" placeholder="3" value=profile.year errorMessage=(fieldError "year")}}
      </div>
      <div class="fields">
        {{> Select_Form_Control label="Number of Seats" placeholder="5" value=profile.seats errorMessage=(fieldError "seats")}}
      </div>
</div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

**Helper**

```
Template.Profile_Page.events({
 'click #driver_button'(event, instance) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set("showDriverForm",true);
  },
  'click #rider_button'(event, instance) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set("showRiderForm", true);
  },
});

Template.Profile_Page.helpers({
  driverButtonClicked: function(){
    return Session.get("showDriverForm");
  },
  riderButtonClicked: function(){
    return Session.get("showRiderForm");
  }
});
```

### Get values from the fields:

Since you are using text fields, you can use a `change` listener to detect changes to the value in those fields.

Example snipped. (I've added a an id field to uniquely distinguish the form fields.

```
{{> Text_Form_Control id="carModels" label="Car Model" placeholder="Toyota Tacoma 2016" value=profile.car errorMessage=(fieldError "car")}}
        {{> Select_Form_Control id="yearsOwned" label="Years Owned" placeholder="3" value=profile.year errorMessage=(fieldError "year")}}
```

Events will contain:

```
'change #carModels' (event){
    var models=event.target.value;
},
'change #yearsOwned' (event){
  var years=event.target.value;
}
```